# Placing PYGTK IMAGE at a particular pixel position

Tags: gtk, pygtk, gtk2

How to place an image at a particular x and y pixel position on a window by code in pygtk?
I have tried xalign and yalign after reading [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3703509/set-position-of-image-in-a-window-using-pygtk) but it only aligns the image. I will use this code to make a grid of images. 
Please help

Comment: What widgets are currently in the window? Are you planning to write a single widget to display this grid of images and put this widget in a window?

Answer (score 0):

Try GtkFixed.

GtkFixed is a container, position of its child widget can be set by:

```
gtk_fixed_put(GtkFixed *fixed, GtkWidget *widget, gint x, gint y);
```